# How to test IAP with Sandbox User in the Sandbox environment?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, in-app-purchase

I can test in the Xcode environment.
I can test with TestFlight which uses a REAL Apple Id to make purchases in the Sandbox Environment.

But how do I test with a Sandbox User in the Sandbox Environment? Because I need to be able to clear out my Sandbox user purchase history so that I can test first purchases again.

I've been reading through the documents and I feel like each particular doc jumps over the piece of info that I need. It explains how to create a Sandbox Test User and I've done that. I did plenty of IAP work many years ago, but things have changed enough that it's not working as I expect. When I read the docs, I feel like I can't find the missing piece.

When I test in a simulator with Xcode, it does my IAP transactions in the Xcode environment. That makes sense.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox

This page says:

> To run your app using your Sandbox Apple ID, build and run your app
> from Xcode.

But when I test on a physical device installing directly from Xcode, it also does my IAP transactions in the Xcode environment. I thought this would put me in the Sandbox environment, but it didn't. The Xcode transactions manager shows the transactions. The initial purchase view controller didn't reference the Sandbox at all and the "You're All Set" alert shows Environment: Xcode instead of Environment: Sandbox.

[image]

When I put a test build into TestFlight and test using that version, my IAP transactions are happening in production using my real Apple Id (but I'm not actually charged for any transactions).

I assumed that testing in TestFlight would give me the Sandbox environment, but it happens in the Production environment. (The purchase view controller doesn't show Sandbox and the "You're All Set" alert doesn't show Sandbox.)

So, how do I test in the Sandbox? Every way I try to test either puts me in the Xcode environment or the Production Environment.

What am I missing?

I've logged out of my real Apple id on my phone and then logged in with the Sandbox User credentials I created in AppStore Connect. But when I tried to test the app, by installing from Xcode it still says I'm in the Xcode test environment. When I create transactions, those transactions show up in the Xcode Transaction Manager.

How do I test in the Sandbox environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between IAP being in "Xcode" mode versus being in "Sandbox" mode is whether you setup a StoreKit Configuration or not on your target's scheme.

In Xcode select the Product menu and go to Scheme, then "Edit Scheme...". Select Run on the left side and then go to the Options tab.

For the "StoreKit Configuration" setting you will get Xcode mode if you select a specific configuration. You will get Sandbox mode if you set this option to None even when running the app from Xcode.

None of this applies when running from TestFlight. In TestFlight you are in full production mode.

To verify this I logged into a sandbox account in the Settings app under App Store -> SANDBOX ACCOUNT. I then ran my app via Xcode and went through some IAP in my app. When the StoreKit Configuration was set to None the IAP screens showed "Sandbox". When the StoreKit Configuration was set to a specific storekit file the IAP screens showed "Xcode".

Answer (score -1):

This is what the Apple documentation should have mentioned in [Testing in-app purchases with sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox):

> When testing in-app purchases in the sandbox environment, make sure
> you’re running a development-signed build of your app;
> production-signed builds use the production environment.